# Reference request - Weyl's integration formula

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, reductive-groups

Is there a reference discussing in an organized way (with a proof) the Weyl integration formula for a reductive group over a local field (Archimedean or not), expressing the Haar integral on the group as a sum over Levi's of integrals over the elliptic elements in the Levi of orbital-like integrals?

Thank you!
Sasha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 7 of Kottwitz's article in the 2003 Clay proceedings [here](http://www.claymath.org/library/proceedings/cmip04.pdf) has what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks like a good reference.

Comment: I had no idea that those proceedings were online!  Thanks!